# PubCenter/Admob In Cocos2dx C++ Windows 8.1 Universal App

Tags: admob, cocos2d-x, ads

I'm trying to integrate ads into my Cocos2dx game written in C++. Both the Windows and Windows Phone projects use shared C++ code and a .XAML file as far as I know for the Universal App. How do I add a simple banner ad to the game using Google Admob or Microsoft pubCenter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admob can't be used right now with Universal apps, the (really buggy) control is only available for Windows Phone 8.0

For pubcenter, I recommend this link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/advertising-mobile-windows-phone-ads-walkthroughs-81-xaml%28v=msads.20%29.aspx